# IPB - Include template in custom page

Tags: php, templates, template-engine, ipb

I'm willing to have custom page which uses same template as my IP.Board but I want to evade using any plugins to achieve same.
Currently I have:

```
<?PHP
//define( 'IPS_ENFORCE_ACCESS', TRUE ); // Important so it does not redirect to forums
define( 'IPB_THIS_SCRIPT', 'public' );
require_once( 'initdata.php' );
require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH . 'sources/base/ipsRegistry.php' );
require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH . 'sources/base/ipsController.php' );

$ipbRegistry    = ipsRegistry::instance();
$ipbRegistry->init();

$output = $ipbRegistry->getClass('output');
$output->addContent("<h1>Well, this is a test! </h1>");
$output->setTitle("Test page");
$output->sendOutput();
```

And this code actually works barely well. It outputs custom page, with IP.Board template also, but template is default one, not one I use on my forums. 
How to include IP.Board template in my custom page?
Probably I missing some call in my script, some call to setup template which should be used?
The custom page I willing to use is in same directory and on same domain.

For MyBB it worked like this:

```
<?PHP
require "global.php";

// Some simple calls to initialize and set variables used below
// -------------------------------------------------------------
// Output HTML + required code from MyBB previously defined
echo "<!doctype html>
{$mybb_header}
<body>
<p>Some content</p>
{$mybb_footer}
</body>
</html>";
```